# Dynamic way to handle conditional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Coming from jQuery into the world of React, i'm working on a problem that's asking to display details from a JSON response using a show/hide button. My current implementation just has me using CSS to show/hide a sibling div. Is there a way to instead dynamically render the specific  component instead of loading all of them on the page and using CSS to control their display?

Component:

```
<ul>
  {countries.map(country => 
    <li key={country.Countriesalpha2Code}>
      {country.name} <button onClick={showDetails}>show</button>
      <div style={{display: 'none'}}>
        <Details country={country} />
      </div>
    </li>
  )}
</ul>
```

Function:

```
const showDetails = (event) => {
  let target = event.target
  let sibling = target.nextSibling

  if(sibling.style.display == 'none'){
    sibling.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    sibling.style.display = 'none'
  }

  if(target.textContent == 'show') {
    target.textContent = 'hide'
  } else {
    target.textContent = 'show'
  }
}
```

Comment: "Better" how? Stack Overflow questions should elicit fact-based, objective answers, not opinions.

Comment: Sure, so if we were to make this into something that displayed, let's say 100 entries in a list, we'd be populating the dom with 100 extra <Detail /> components that the user doesn't necessarily want to load. In this case better would be dynamically displaying a single <Detail /> component if a user decides to click the show/hide button

Comment: Please [edit] the question so that it does not ask for opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't be modifying element states in callbacks. Instead, you could make the expanded/hidden state of each element a state atom, like so:

```
const CountryDetail = ({ country }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleExpanded = React.useCallback(() => setExpanded((expanded) => !expanded), []);
  return (
    <li>
      {country.name}
      <button onClick={toggleExpanded}>show</button>
      {expanded ? <Details country={country} /> : null}
    </li>
  );
};

const Countries = () => (
  <ul>
    {countries.map((country) => (
      <CountryDetail key={country.Countriesalpha2Code} country={country} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Comment: Ah, you know it never occurred to me to make the <li> items a component. Let me unpack this EDIT: Ok i got it now, thanks for the advice!